# What are the non-trivial use-cases of attributes in WebGL/OpenGL in general?

Tags: opengl-es, webgl, shader

I'm making a WebGL game and eventually came up with a pretty convenient concept of object templates, when the game objects of the same kind (say, characters of the same race) are using the same template (which means: buffers, attributes and shader program), and are instanced from that template by specifying a set of uniforms (which are, in fact, the most common difference between the same-kind objects: model matrix, textures, bones positions, etc). For making independent objects with their own deep-copy of buffers, I just deep-copy and re-initialize the original template and start instantiating new objects from it.

But after that I started having doubts. Say, if I start using morphing on objects, by explicit editing of the vertices, this approach will require me to make a separate template for every object of such kind (otherwise, they would start morphing in exactly the same phase). Which is probably fine for this very case, 'cause I'll most likely need to recalculate normals and even texture coordinates, which means – most of the buffers.

But what if I'm missing some very common case of using attributes, say, blood decals, which will require me to update only a small piece of the buffer? In that case, it would be much more reasonable to have two buffers for each object: a common one that is shared by them all and the one for blood decals, which is unique for every single of them. And, as blood is usually spilled on everything, this sounds pretty reasonable, so that we would save a lot of space by storing vertices, normals and such without their unnecessary duplication.

I haven't tried implementing decals yet, so honestly not even sure if implementing them using vertex painting (textured or not) is the right choice. But I'm also pretty sure there are some commonly used attributes aside from vertices, normals and texture coordinates.

Here are some that I managed to come up with myself:

- decals (probably better to be modelled as separate objects?)
- bullet holes and such (same as decals maybe?)

Any thoughts?

UPD: as all this might sound confusing, I want to clarify: I do understand that using as few buffers as possible is a good thing, this is exactly why I'm trying to use this templates concept. My question is: what are the possible cases when using a single buffer and a single element buffer (with both of them shared between similar objects) for a template is going to stab me in the back?

Answer (score 2):

Keeping a giant chunk of data that won't change on the card is incredibly useful for saving bandwidth.  Additionally, you probably won't be directly changing the vertices positions once they are on the card.  Instead you will probably morph them with passed in uniforms in the Vertex shader through Skeletal animation.  Read about it here: [Skeletal Animation](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Skeletal_Animation)

Do keep in mind though, that in Key frame animation with meshes, you **would** keep a bunch of buffers on the card each in a different key frame pose of the animation.  However, you would then load whatever two key frames you want to interpolate over in as attributes and then blend between them (You can have more than two).  [Keyframe Animation](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Keyframe_Animation)

Additionally, with the introduction of Transformation Feedback, (No you don't get to use it in WebGL, it became core in OpenGL 3.0, WebGL is based on OpenGL ES 2.0, which is based on OpenGL 2.0) you can start keeping calculated data GPU side.  In other words, you can do a giant particle system simulation in the vertex or geometry shader and then store the calculated data into another buffer, then use that buffer in the next frame **without having to have a round trip from the GPU to CPU**  Read about them here: [Transform Feedback](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Transform_Feedback) and here: [Transform Feedback how to](http://open.gl/feedback)

In general, you don't want to touch buffers once they are on the card, especially every frame.  Instead load several and use pointers to that data in shaders as attributes.

Comment: Yeah, I mentioned bones (i.e. skeletal animation). Also, I probably won't be using keyframe animation (which is close to vertices direct editing, expect we trade bandwidth for memory).
And yes, I do get that reusing buffers and switching between them as rarely as possible is good. My question was: what are the common cases when a single buffer for the entire object is going to bite me (keyframe animation is an answer, indeed)?